# Selenium return webcontent

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium to automate web gui tests. I would like to know, if selenium can return html which contains rendered html as a result of some button click?

For example, initial html has `<div id="errorSection"></div>`. Now, selenium clicks on a button and errorSection div tag is filled up like this:

```
<div id="errorSection">
<ol>
   <li>Password must be 8 characters long</li>
   <li>Username has already been taken</li>
 </ol>
</div>
```

Is selenium able to send back rendered html with rendered content?

Comment: Yes you'll get the render content. Note that it will not contain the content created by CSS (pseudo element).

Comment: You mean, you want to get text when it would present into div. Right??

Comment: Yes. I would like to get the initial html + html rendered into div tag